# Libxml2 refuses to parse XML entities

Tags: ios, svg, libxml2

libxml on iOS categorically refuses to parse this seemingly valid XML file (part of the SVG spec!):

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/coords/PreserveAspectRatio.svg
```

It complains:

```
Error Domain=1 Code=27 "Entity 'Smile' not defined
UserInfo=0x7655730
{
   lineNumber=26,
   NSLocalizedDescription=Entity 'Smile' not defined,
   bonusInfo1=Smile,
   columnNumber=25
}
```

...and returns a WARNING level error for each entity. There seems to be no way to force it to do what the docs imply it does (parse entities by default). There's a mysterious pseudo-explanation here (http://www.xmlsoft.org/entities.html) that says it's very difficult and no-one should do it themselves ... but libxml doesn't seem to do it either :(.

Here's the setup struct, to confirm that I'm not providing any override for entity parsing:

```
static xmlSAXHandler SAXHandler = {
    NULL,                       /* internalSubset */
    NULL,                       /* isStandalone   */
    NULL,                       /* hasInternalSubset */
    NULL,                       /* hasExternalSubset */
    NULL,                       /* resolveEntity */
    NULL,                       /* getEntity */
    NULL,                       /* entityDecl */
    NULL,                       /* notationDecl */
    NULL,                       /* attributeDecl */
    NULL,                       /* elementDecl */
    NULL,                       /* unparsedEntityDecl */
    NULL,                       /* setDocumentLocator */
    NULL,                       /* startDocument */
    NULL,                       /* endDocument */
    NULL,                       /* startElement*/
    NULL,                       /* endElement */
    NULL,                       /* reference */
    charactersFoundSAX,         /* characters */
    NULL,                       /* ignorableWhitespace */
    NULL,                       /* processingInstruction */
    NULL,                       /* comment */
    NULL,                       /* warning */
    errorEncounteredSAX,        /* error */
    NULL,                       /* fatalError //: unused error() get all the errors */
    NULL,                       /* getParameterEntity */
    cDataFoundSAX,              /* cdataBlock */
    NULL,                       /* externalSubset */
    XML_SAX2_MAGIC,
    NULL,
    startElementSAX,            /* startElementNs */
    endElementSAX,              /* endElementNs */
    structuredError,                       /* serror */
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an enormous bug in libxml that's been around for - it seems - some time.

The docs (http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlCreatePushParserCtxt) say this:

```
xmlParserCtxtPtr    xmlCreatePushParserCtxt (xmlSAXHandlerPtr sax, 
                         void * user_data, 
                         const char * chunk, 
                         int size, 
                         const char * filename)
sax:    a SAX handler
user_data:  The user data returned on SAX callbacks
```

but what they should say is:

```
sax:    a SAX handler
user_data:  YOU MUST NOT USE THIS BECAUSE LIBXML IS BADLY
 BROKEN INTERNALLY. NEVER PASS ANYTHING EXCEPT NULL TO
 THIS PARAMETER. ENTITIES WILL NEVER WORK IF YOU PASS
 ANYTHING EXCEPT NULL.
```

i.e. you cannot use the "userdata" pointer, and you have to instead code your own static variables (somewhere) and use them to keep track of state, as libxml won't allow you to track state itself.

(I eventually found a reference on a mailing list where someone asked why this is broken and requesting that the docs be updated with a warning)

Incidentally, this explains some entity-related problems I've seen on other iOS projects that used libxml, I think. Many days wasted on this single bug / bad documentation :(. Sigh.